Odoo with Docker Can't find the configuration file
I installed odoo with docker and it working well but I can't find the configuration file.
I looked to the logs I found mention that "2024-08-26 13:15:16,759 1 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf"
but there is no folder under name of odoo at etc. I got an wrong massage "unable to find : /etc/odoo".

Is the ubuntu screen you provided is your container?
/etc/odoo/odoo.conf is indeed sure to be in your container if you are running by Odoo official Docker image. You can view it easily by using Docker desktop.
For myself, my docker compose create a volume from my local machine to the container machine on the odoo.conf.
Add this to your odoo container:
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/odoo

./config is the folder in my local machine that store the file odoo.conf.

Yes that mentioned path to the config is the container path not the host's system path. Defining a volume either in docker-compose.yml or on docker run should be enough to find and change the odoo.conf.

I' am very appreciated Thank you guys
